# Openpyxl: How to compare cell values in two worksheets

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Does anyone know how to iterate through specific columns in multiple worksheets to compare the particular cell values in the worksheets? The two worksheets are identical in format but the cells in my columns of interest can have different values. I'm trying to determine if there are changed values in the two different sheets using openpyxl. The code I have is below. m1 and m2 represent the two sheets I'm iterating columns through. Currently, I have the cells giving me values like 0->0->8->4 rather than simply displaying the old and new value like this 0->4. Any help is appreciated!

```
for col_cells in m1.iter_cols(min_row=uniqueID.row,max_row=uniqueID.row,min_col=start,max_col=last):
       for cell in col_cells:
          for col_cells2 in m2.iter_cols(min_row=uniqueID2.row,max_row=uniqueID2.row,min_col=start2,max_col=last2):
             for cell2 in col_cells2:
                 
                    if cell.value!=cell2.value and printed ==False: 
                        
                        strcellval=str(cell.value)
                        strcellval2=str(cell2.value)
                        delta_value=strcellval+" ---> "+strcellval2
                       
                        cell2.value=delta_value
                    else: 
                         break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I didn't use your code. I think you had unneeded for loops there.
In addition I think this is more elegant way to do.
try this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


def char_range(c1, c2):
    """Generates the characters from `c1` to `c2`, inclusive."""
    for c in range(ord(c1), ord(c2)+1):
        yield chr(c)


def compare(m1, m2, start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col):
    rows = char_range(start_row, end_row)
    cols = range(start_col, end_col)

    for row in rows:
        for col in cols:
            strcellval = m1[f'{row}{col}'].internal_value
            strcellval2 = m2[f'{row}{col}'].internal_value
            if strcellval != strcellval2:
                print(f"{strcellval} ---> {strcellval2}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m1 = load_workbook('test.xlsx').active
    m2 = load_workbook('test2.xlsx').active
    
    compare(m1, m2, 'a', 'c', 1, 3)
```